# HP SAS expander maps all drives to slot id 0

Tags: hardware-raid, sas

I recently bought a used 6Gbps 24 port HP SAS expander (468406-B21/487738-001) because it is cheap and presumably has a high degree of compatibility. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work with more than one disk, because it apparently maps all disks to slot 0, confusing both RAID controllers and HBAs.

The card came with firmware 2.08, upgrading to the latest version (2.10) did not change anything.

When I attach it to a PERC H700, H310 or LSI 9260, all of the disks are mapped to slot 0, which makes it impossible to distinguish them. It also confused the RAID controller - if I remove a disk, it might lose two disks and so on, and it might not even boot.

For example, with two SATA disks attached:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG      Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model             Sp 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2:0       3 UGood -  111.25 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST9120822AS       U  
2:0       5 UGood -  185.75 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B TOSHIBA MK2035GSS U  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here, both disks are mapped to enclosure 2, slot 0 and cannot be distinguished in subsequent commands. I run into similar problems when attaching the expander to a "dumb" HBA such as a LSI-9211 based controller.

There is a large number of reports of people using this expander with the exact same firmware version(s) as I do without any problems, and all the controllers work fine with the other backplanes I tried (Supermicro LSI-based ones), so I wonder if I am doing something wrong or the card is somehow broken.

An example **show termlog** output of an H700 when attaching two disks is shown below:

```
02/04/18  3:09:34: iopiEvent: EVENT_SAS_DISCOVERY
02/04/18  3:09:34: DM_HandleDiscEvent: Discovery started on Port 0

02/04/18  3:09:34: iopiEvent: MPI2_EVENT_SAS_TOPOLOGY_CHANGE_LIST 
02/04/18  3:09:34: DM_HandleTopologyChgEvnt: PhysicalPort=0 NumberOfPhys=x25 NumEntries=x0c StartPhy=xc 
02/04/18  3:09:34: ExpStatus=x03 PhysicalPort=0 EnclosureHandle=x0002 Expander devHandle=x0009 - Exp RESPONDING
02/04/18  3:09:34: Phy changed - phy 0c devHandle 0000 linkRate 00 curLinkRate 0
02/04/18  3:09:34: Phy changed - phy 0f devHandle 0000 linkRate 00 curLinkRate 0
02/04/18  3:09:34: Device ADDED - phy x14 devHandle x000c parentDevHdl x0009 phyNum x14 slot x37 deviceInfo=x00000081 sasAddr=5001438022c783d4
02/04/18  3:09:34: Device ADDED - phy x17 devHandle x000d parentDevHdl x0009 phyNum x17 slot x34 deviceInfo=x00000081 sasAddr=5001438022c783d7
02/04/18  3:09:34: DM_DevMgrIsChipInit 0 State 400 
02/04/18  3:09:35: iopiDiscoveryComplete SubSystem 2 Count 9 InitState 1

02/04/18  3:09:35: iopiEvent: EVENT_SAS_DISCOVERY
02/04/18  3:09:35: DM_HandleDiscEvent: Discovery Completed on Port 0

02/04/18  3:09:36: DM_DevSSUCallback: DevId x0006 errCount 0 Retry 0 Status 2
02/04/18  3:09:36: DM_DevSSUCallback: SENSE Len 12 ResponseCode 70 senseKey 6 asc 29 ascq 0
02/04/18  3:09:36: DM_DevMgrIsChipInit 0 State 400 
02/04/18  3:09:38: DM_DevSSUCallback: DevId x0007 errCount 0 Retry 0 Status 2
02/04/18  3:09:38: DM_DevSSUCallback: SENSE Len 12 ResponseCode 70 senseKey 6 asc 29 ascq 0
02/04/18  3:09:38: devId 6 isn't directly attached
02/04/18  3:09:38: devId 6 - slot num - 6
02/04/18  3:09:38: devId 7 isn't directly attached
02/04/18  3:09:38: devId 7 - slot num - 7
02/04/18  3:09:38:  DM_DevNotifyRAID: Notify Done. Check for Removal 
02/04/18  3:09:38: gDevInfo=842360a0, size=160
02/04/18  3:09:38: Total Device = 3  
02/04/18  3:09:38: PD   Flags    State Type Size     S N Vendor   Product          Rev  P C ID SAS Addr         Port Phy DevH BFw  BRev
02/04/18  3:09:38: ---  -------- ----- ---- -------- - - -------- ---------------- ---- - - -- ---------------- ---- --- ---- ---- ----
02/04/18  3:09:38: 2    01400005 00020 0d   0 0 0 0 HP       HP SAS EXP Card  2.10 0 0 0a 5001438022c783e5 00   24  0a    NA   NA
02/04/18  3:09:38: 6    f1400005 00020 00   1749f1af 1 1 0 ATA      TOSHIBA MK2035GS 1D   0 0 0c 5001438022c783d4 00   14  0c    NA   NA
02/04/18  3:09:38: 7    f1400005 00020 00   df94baf 1 1 0 ATA      ST9120822AS      D    0 0 0d 5001438022c783d7 00   17  0d    NA   NA
02/04/18  3:09:38: 100  00400005 00020 03   0 0 0 0 LSI      SMP/SGPIO/SEP    4651 0 0 ffff                0 00   ff  00    NA   NA

02/04/18  3:09:38: PhyId 4 Sas 5001438022c783e6 Type 2 IsSata 0, Smp 1:1
02/04/18  3:09:38: PhyId 5 Sas 5001438022c783e6 Type 2 IsSata 0, Smp 1:1
02/04/18  3:09:38: PhyId 6 Sas 5001438022c783e6 Type 2 IsSata 0, Smp 1:1
02/04/18  3:09:38: PhyId 7 Sas 5001438022c783e6 Type 2 IsSata 0, Smp 1:1
02/04/18  3:09:38: PhyId 0 Sas 0 Type 0 IsSata 0, Smp 0:0
02/04/18  3:09:38: PhyId 0 Sas 0 Type 0 IsSata 0, Smp 0:0
02/04/18  3:09:38: PhyId 0 Sas 0 Type 0 IsSata 0, Smp 0:0
02/04/18  3:09:38: PhyId 0 Sas 0 Type 0 IsSata 0, Smp 0:0
02/04/18  3:09:38: Load Balance Statistics Path0PDs 3 Path1PDs 0
02/04/18  3:09:38: EVT#07666-02/04/18  3:09:38:  91=Inserted: PD 06(e0x02/s0)
02/04/18  3:09:38: EVT#07667-02/04/18  3:09:38: 247=Inserted: PD 06(e0x02/s0) Info: enclPd=02, scsiType=0, portMap=00, sasAddr=5001438022c783d4,0000000000000000
02/04/18  3:09:38: EVT#07668-02/04/18  3:09:38:  91=Inserted: PD 07(e0x02/s0)
02/04/18  3:09:38: EVT#07669-02/04/18  3:09:38: 247=Inserted: PD 07(e0x02/s0) Info: enclPd=02, scsiType=0, portMap=00, sasAddr=5001438022c783d7,0000000000000000
```

**Update:**

If I ask the expander for its additional element sense page, it lists a "device slot number: 0" for all slots - other expanders list increasing numbers here, and I suspect this is the indirect cause of my problem. I also tried this expander on a newer H740P controller, and it lists the drives as directly attached (not in an enclosure), with made-up slot ids - this is an improvement, but it suffers from other problems, such as listing a western digital enclosure (i.e. it lists one of the attached drives as enclosure).

I also bought another of these expanders, and the behaviour is identical, so it is unlikely that the expander is broken - it seems the H700 requires slot ids, and the HP SAS expander simply doesn't support them - or is there a way to re-assign the device slot numbers in the aes page somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite some research, it seems that the PMC-Sierra based SAS expanders list all device slot numbers as 0, and this is allowed by the SAS specification, as the other diagnostic pages and the smp discovery protocol don't claim the device has valid slot numbers.

So the problem is caused by a rather buggy SAS implementation in the LSI SAS controllers, which enforce the use of slot numbers even when they don't exist, instead of using disk ids, which are unique, or another mechanism (such as sas addresses).

I don't know if this is merely a user interface deficiency in tools (such as storcli) or it goes deeper. At least the disovery problems in the Perc H700 are due to a buggy implementation of sas topology discovery, which is specified by the SAS standard and does not use slot numbers. HBA drivers from LSI seem to have similar problems.